# Ubuntu graphics lost due to incomplete upgrade

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade

I was using Ubuntu 14.04 and tried to upgrade it to 16.04 LTS.

While upgrading, the download was completed but the installation was in progress. In this situation my computer was shutdown. Now the boot loader is seen but ubuntu is not being booted.

Pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 it gives text screen of Ubuntu but not the graphics screen. The screen becomes black!! Please give suggestions.

Comment: Are you able to get to recovery mode? (Press esc when the system first starts (within the first few seconds after the BIOS/EFI screen comes up). You should get a grub menu that will give you options to choose a different kernel, or to use recovery mode.

Answer (score 0):

If you can get to recovery mode, choose to open a root terminal (with networking), then run this command:

`dpkg --configure -a`

Once that is complete, run:

`apt install -f`

If you system was able to connect to the network, it will download any packages that are required to fix the situation.

If the system is not able to complete the second command (due to lack of a network connection), reboot the system (it should theoretically be bootable if `dpkg --configure -a` worked), and log in (if the graphical screen comes up), then run this command (`apt install -f`) again.

Comment: Both commands worked. The syatem recovered !! Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: @Kisor if that is the case, you should upvote the answer and/or mark the question answered by clicking the tick box next to my answer.

Comment: How to do that @RolandiXor ?

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/tour